# Any way to determine capacity of old washer/dryer?

Tags: dryer, washing-machine

My parents have a Whirlpool washer (model LA7000XS) and dryer (model LE7080XSW0) from 1987.  They want to replace them, but want to make sure the capacities of the new washer and dryer are at least as large as the Whirlpool ones.

They still have the manuals for the Whirlpool washer and dryer, but the manuals don't mention the capacity at all.  Neither do any of the stickers in the machines.  Is there any way to find out what their capacity is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to page 4 of the [LA700XS manual](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/193964/Whirlpool-La7000xs.html?page=4#manual) the washing machine's extra large load is 21.7 gallons which would translate to 2.9 cubic feet.

Most online buying guides for dryers recommend getting one that is double the capacity of your washer so the clothes have room to move.

Comment: Then there are those of us who try to pack several washer-loads into one drier-load... so more than double might actually make sense.

Comment: Packing multiple washes in one dryer load is an inefficient approach, IMHO.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Don't you think it depends upon what one is optimizing on when determining efficiency? For example, time spent moving laundry between machines and baskets could be a legitimate measure of efficiency for some people.

Answer (score 1):

Most washing machine models come in sizes from 2.45 cubic feet to 3.3 cubic feet. The size of the washing machine is important because it determines the capacity of the load, and you need a machine that fits the size of your family. The higher the skill level the larger the dressing space. Since the washing bowl is a drum, you can use the equation to find the size of the drum to determine the capacity of your washer.

**Step 1**
It is measured by measuring the depth of the wash. For the front filling machine, measure from the back of the washing machine to the front. The depth of the top washcloth is measured from the end of the bowl to the top. For example, a washing machine may have a depth of 1.75 meters.

**Step 2**
The diameter of the waist is measured. This is the distance on one side of the hip. For example, the inside of a washing machine may be 1.5 meters.

**Step 3**
Divide by two and a quarter by its diameter. In this example, 1.5 of 2 is equal to 0.75, and 0.75 of the power of 2 is 0.5625.

**Step 4**
Multiply the number calculated in step 3 by the depth of the hips. In the example 0.5625 multiplied by 1.75 equals 0.98.
**Step %**
Multiply pi by the number calculated in step 4 to determine the amplitude. Pi is around 3.14. For example, 0.98 by 3.14 is equivalent to a washer capacity of 3.1 cubic meters.